# using math with a powershell function

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to perform math within a function. outside of the function I'm able to get it to work, but in the function I get 
"Method invocation failed because [system.int32[]] doesn't contain a method named 'op_division'"

`function fix-size {
        param(
        [int[]]$fixme
        )
          if ($fixme -lt 1mb) {
            $fixme1 = ([system.math]::round($fixme / 1kb, 1))
            } 
         write-host $fixme1
        }`

Comment: Why do you have `[int[]]` for the param?

Answer (score 4):

The '[int[]]' syntax indicates that $fixme is an ARRAY of ints, and you can't perform division on an array.

So you either need to change your parameter definition to`param( [int]$fixme )` OR, if you really want to operate on multiple numbers, you'll need to do more processing inside the function, like so:

```
function fix-size { 
    param ([int[]]$fixme)
    foreach ($number in $fixme) {
        if ($number -lt 1mb) {
            ([system.math]::round($number / 1kb, 1))
        }
    }
}
```